in VS code can I see the value of a variable that is included from another file?
I'm doing a bit of cypress automated testing but this question is probably more flat out js or vscode.
I have an object in a file that I export like this
const ui = {
      profile:{
        details:{
          firstName: "#collapse1 input[placeholder='First Name']"
        }
      }
    }
module.exports = ui;

And I include that file into my test project like this:
const ui = require("../../../support/locators.js");

//Cool, now I can do a cypress get using the UI object that I required above. 
cy.get(ui.profile.details.firstName).click();

//here is how I used to do things
const LASTNAME_SELECTOR = "#collapse1 input[placeholder='Last Name']";
cy.get(LASTNAME_SELECTOR).click();

The approach works fine and looks feels better to me from a coding perspective but I miss one feature from the original approach (a constant in the same file)... When I include the object I cant hover over the object and see the current value like I could with the constant.
Is there a way to import/require an object so that vs can show me the value in the object when I hover over the object in code??

I'm still hoping for a better answer but right clicking and "Goto Definition" or right clicking followed by Alt + F12 to "peek definition" is the next best thing to hovering.
